# In-Page Editor Line Distortion

Tags: visualforce, developer-productivity

The SFDC In-page editor has always had distortion for me, and I'm just wondering if it's just a lousy browser plugin they're using or if someone has found a good browser / operating system combination that stops the ***obnoxious distortion***.

*Obviously Salesforce doesn't have much interest in fixing it*: as it's been this way on multiple operating systems and browsers I've used since I've used Salesforce.

**However, my frustration with their other developer tools has lead me to use it occasionally and it's always the same:**[image: SFDC In-page developer mode editor is always distorted. OSX+Chrome]

Comment: What browswer/os combinations have you tried?

Comment: OSX+Chrome, OSX+Firefox, OSX+Safari, Pretty much everything on Windows 7, it's always there.

Comment: Could you use the Chrome dev tools to inspect the underlying DOM elements? I suspect something odd is occurring at that level. E.g. There are actually 2 paragraphs there and one is being positioned behind the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try to zoom the screen a bit ctrl +  OR click on the A to increase the font size , this should probably fix the text ghosting, surprising but that's what it is :(
[image]

Comment: Yeah it looks like it was browser zoom. What a lousy plugin.

Comment: The plugin is designed to work at 100% zoom, no more and no less. It's definitely frustrating, I agree. The Developer Tools window doesn't seem to suffer from this, though, although it will wickedly eat up your API calls.