# Ghost Text in Apex Class Editor

Tags: code, text, syntax-highlighting

I seem to have turned some weird setting on in Salesforce that "highlights" the line of code that the cursor is currently at. Whatever it is, it doesn't work very well and covers up text that I need to see. What is this and how do I turn it off?

I've googled the problem and come up with nothing. Here's some pictures of what I'm talking about.

[image: Weird Text]
[image: Weird Text 2]

Comment: Try zooming in or out. This has been an issue for a while but I can't find a link right at the moment.

Comment: Yah, it looks like I was zoomed in 110% and didn't notice it. Changing to 100% fixed this for me. Thankyou!

Comment: It's `Visualforce`, but someone else ran into the same problem a few years ago on SFSE: [In-Page Editor Line Distortion](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14527/in-page-editor-line-distortion)

Comment: Wait, you still use the old-school editor?

Comment: I use eclipse, the console, and the old-school editor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have run into this issue before and fixed it by zooming in or zooming out to adjust the display. You can see that this issue has been around since at least 2013: [In-Page Editor Line Distortion](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14527/in-page-editor-line-distortion).

For most browsers:

- Zoom In - <kbd>CTRL</kbd> / <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>
- Zoom Out - <kbd>CTRL</kbd> / <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>
- Zoom Reset - <kbd>CTRL</kbd> / <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>

Comment: I'd add that you can use Ctrl-0 or Cmd-0 on most browsers to reset to the default zoom.